# Part of texture becomes invisible

Tags: texturing

[image]So I just made a simple tree model and it all looked fine, but then when I applied a texture, a part of my "leaves" became invisible, in solid mode it looks normal but when i change to texture mode parts of the leaves become entirely transparent even tho there is no transparency on my texture. As you can see on the picture, the branch is visible trough the leaves.

Comment: Can you check if the normals are inside out? If that's the issue, selecting that part in edit mode and pressing Alt + N "Recalculate outside" should  do the trick.

Comment: Seems like i fixed it! I just randomly cheked some property and now it works, I'm not sure what it said because it dissappeared after i cheked it, but it said something with "normals" and "inside".
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I also wen't ahead and fixed another model with the same problem and when trying to fix it, I found a thing under the "Mesh tools" called "Recalculate normals", so that's also a way to fix it, tho Alt + "N" does not seem to work, because when i press it, literally nothing happens